# Obtain post by id without order in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am try to get this page by ids like this.

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post__in' => array(2,1220,3731,696,1899,380)
  );
    $query = query_posts($args);
```

this is ok, but I obtain the post by order first 3731 and last 2, buy I don't want any order I want this order, 2, 1220, 3731, 696... etc

any idea!!

Answer (score 1):

add the `orderby` parameter

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post__in' => array(2,1220,3731,696,1899,380)
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
  );
    $query = query_posts($args);
```

[CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Mark thanks for all I try this too but no work.

Finally I found the solution!

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'meta_key' => 'ordenacion',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'post__in' => array(2,1220,3731,696,1899,380)
  );
    $query = query_posts($args);
```

I create a field custom and order by the value of meta_key